# Question of sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

Option 1 discard. First given condition says that terms are alternating and second condition says that terms are decreasing. So series in option 1 becomes alternating and decreasing series. Hence by Leibniz test, it is convergent in R.
Option 2 is also false. It is not necessarily converge to 0. I have no idea for options 3 and 4. Please help me in this problem. I'm not know how to start the solution of this problem.

Comment: Please type the problem out with $\LaTeX$ and **Markdown** in order to get more attention.

Comment: Also, it is recommended that you show your effort.

Answer (score 1):

For 3, note that $u_{n}\neq0$ as $|u_{n-1}|<\frac{|u_{n}|}{2}$. Note that $u_{n}<0$ for all odd $n\geq 13$ and $u_{n}>0$ for all even $n\geq13$ hence $u_{2n-1}-u_{2n}<\frac{u_{2n-1}}{2}$. From this it follows that
$$\sum_{n=13}^{\infty}u_{n}=\sum_{n=7}^{\infty}u_{2n-1}+u_{2n}<\sum_{n=7}^{\infty}\frac{u_{2n-1}}{2}<0$$
so as the series converges it must converge to a non-zero $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

For 4 the proof is similar.

Comment: Floris claaasseens.Thanks. Please tell me that my approach to discard options 1,2 is right or wrong?

Comment: Approach for option 1 and 2 is fine, you could even use the answer for 3/4 to show that the option 2 is false.

Comment: How is 3/4 answer obtained?

Comment: That is given in the answer I gave above.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help.